# Will a query which uses IS NULL always perform bad on large tables?

Tags: query-performance, mysql-8.0, aws-aurora

I've got the following table :

```
CREATE TABLE `file` (
  `id` char(36) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `track_id` char(36) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(3) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `quality` int DEFAULT '0',
  `size` int DEFAULT '0',
  `duration` float DEFAULT '0',
  `bitrate` int DEFAULT '0',
  `samplerate` int DEFAULT '0',
  `updated` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '2000-01-01 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK_file_track` (`track_id`),
  KEY `file_size` (`size`),
  KEY `file_type` (`type`),
  KEY `file_quality` (`quality`),
  KEY `file_ttq` (`track_id`,`type`,`quality`),
  CONSTRAINT `file_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`track_id`) REFERENCES `track` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The table has 5.870.674 rows.

The below query takes about 30 seconds to complete on that table. It finds files of type `WAV` and quality `1` which does not have a corresponding file of type `MP3` and quality `1`. Files are related to each other through `track_id`.

```sql
select SQL_NO_CACHE * 
from file as f1
left join file as f2 on f1.track_id = f2.track_id 
                    and f2.type = 'MP3' 
                    and f2.quality = 1
where f1.type = 'WAV' 
  and f1.quality = 1 
  and f2.track_id is null
limit 100;
```

[image]

```
-> Limit: 100 row(s)  (cost=696287.32 rows=100) (actual time=115.333..31808.476 rows=29 loops=1)
    -> Filter: (f2.track_id is null)  (cost=696287.32 rows=1452798) (actual time=115.332..31808.463 rows=29 loops=1)
        -> Nested loop antijoin  (cost=696287.32 rows=1452798) (actual time=115.330..31808.425 rows=29 loops=1)
            -> Filter: (f1.quality = 1)  (cost=187807.85 rows=1452798) (actual time=0.440..8208.084 rows=1776957 loops=1)
                -> Index lookup on f1 using file_type (type='WAV')  (cost=187807.85 rows=2905597) (actual time=0.438..8017.700 rows=1776957 loops=1)
            -> Index lookup on f2 using file_ttq (track_id=f1.track_id, type='MP3', quality=1)  (cost=0.25 rows=1) (actual time=0.013..0.013 rows=1 loops=1776957)
```

I've been trying to optimize this query in various ways, but I believe the `f2.track_is is null` is what's making this query perform bad. However, I do need to find the files that are missing.

Is there a way to make this query run faster?

Comment: it completes in 0.050 seconds without `f2.track_id is null`.

Comment: `f2.track_id is null` : 29 rows, `f2.track_id is not null` : 1776931 rows

Answer (score 0):

I would add an index on (quality, type, track_id) (columns in that specific order). - [user993](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/993/ypercube%e1%b5%80%e1%b4%b9)

Answer (score 0):

If you want this query to run fast frequently, you’re going to want to add sensible filters to avoid checking the same rows over and over.

The existing plan is slow because you’re doing 1.8 million index lookups to check the existence. You could get this faster with an anti hash join method but MySQL doesn’t support this so nested loops are the only way.

You could rewrite the query so you only do one pass of the table with an aggregation. Something like:

```
select track_id 
from file 
where quality = 1 
and type in ('WAV','MP3') 
group by track_id 
having max(type) = 'WAV' and min(type) = 'WAV'
```

This as a one off query could be faster – [user217655](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/217655/andrew-sayer)

Answer (score 0):

30% of rows match the filter. I do not see the way to improvement, except do not use string-type columns (UUID) for joining.

Instead of `CHAR(36)` for the UUID, pack it to `BINARY(16)` or use autoincremented `(BIG)INT` as `PRIMARY KEY`, and make the UUID `UNIQUE KEY` and `NOT NULL`. And maybe partitioning (if supported in Aurora) by `(type, quality)`. – [user150107](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/150107/akina)